# why python-jl crashes when running julia version 1.2.0

Tags: julia

I usually run julia version 1.0.0 from python-jl:

```
start "python-jl" interpreter
import julia
j = julia.Julia(compiled_modules=False, runtime='/usr/local/bin/julia_v1.0.0')
```

and then whatever code i have .. i include it

```
function = j.include("function.jl") ... etc
```

but now i want to use julia version 1.2.0
so when i execute

```
j = julia.Julia(compiled_modules=False, runtime='/usr/local/bin/julia_v1.2.0')
```

it crashes and writes the following :

```
Two passes with the same argument (-juliaO0) attempted to be registered!
Invalid instruction at 0x7faca4c46c: 0x00000000

signal (4): Illegal instruction
in expression starting at no file:0
_ZN4llvm14PassNameParser14passRegisteredEPKNS_8PassInfoE at /home/nvidia/julia/usr/bin/../lib/libLLVM-6.0.so (unknown line)
Allocations: 9676368 (Pool: 9674771; Big: 1597); GC: 20
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
```

although julia 1.2.0 runs normally without errors .. outside python-jl
i use python-jl because normal python fails when compiled_modules parameter is True .

can anybody help with this ?

i tried to pass both True and false to compiled_modules, nothing changed